# How do I ensure my custom TF2 model shows its texture?

Tags: source-engine

I'm trying to make a new model for the Pyro's default Flamethrower, and I've run into a problem. When I load the new flamethrower model in HLMV or the game, I can't see the texture I made for it, all I see is the pink-and-black checkerboard.

I double-checked my QC, thinking I did something wrong, but the line that says where the texture is:
`$CDMaterials "models\weapons\v_flamethrower"`
is the same as the default (I even decompiled the default model and used its QC.)

The model is stored in the folder "[Path to TF2 folder]\tf\custom\newflamer\models\weapons\c_models\c_flamethrower\c_flamethrower.mdl", and the texture is stored in "[Path to TF2 folder]\tf\custom\newflamer\models\weapons\v_flamethrower\v_flamethrower.vtf".
Even still, all it gives me is the checkered texture.

I removed just the flamethrower model, and the texture still worked (although it was deformed because it was on the wrong model.) So the problem is in my QC. I'm not using a custom .vmt file, just a .vtf and .mdl.

Does anyone know what I did wrong, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is this really the right place to ask this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Dudeson I thought it was. I would've asked it on Arqade, but their Help Center says to ask questions about mod development here.

Comment: The best place to ask TF2 modeling and modding questions is here: http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1464987

Comment: Mod questions are on-topic here, however you *are* likely to get better visibility on forums dedicated to the specific game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely a mismatch between material name in the .mdl file and material name in the QC file. Open the decompiled flamethrower model in your 3D modeling program, copy the assigned material name text, and paste it so your new model has the same material name. I believe the stock flamethrower's material name is `models/weapons/c_items/c_flamethrower.bmp`.

From there, export your .mdl file and it should work without any issues, as long as everything else matches up.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It's my first time making models, so I didn't know that the .smd files had texture names in them (I thought the .vmt/.qc took care of that.) My model loads perfectly with its texture in game.